# Python XPath returning empty lists from Google Project Sunroof

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am attempting to pull the data for square feet and sunlight hours from Google's Project Sunroof, however XPath is only returning blank strings.
This is the relevant code with a Lowe's as the address:

```
   from lxml import

   htmlpageContent=requests.get('https://www.google.com/get/sunroof/building/34.00192560211979/-81.21430071233021/#?f=buy')
   tree = html.fromstring(pageContent.content)

   print(tree.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/address-view/div[1]/div/div/section[1]/div[2]/md-card[1]/ul/li[1]/div[2]"))     
   print(tree.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/address-view/div[1]/div/div/section[1]/div[2]/md-card[1]/ul/li[2]/div[2]/text()"))
```

In this case I want something along the lines of:

`[1,581 hours of usable sunlight per year]`

`[134,199 sq feet available for solar panels ]`

Instead I just get:

`[]`

`[]`

I am new to web scraping like this and xpath, so I haven't been able to test much, but I know that different paths all output a blank list.

Comment: In general I think that style of xpath expression is quite fragile. Anyway, what have you done to debug this? How do you typically debug this kind of web scraping?

Comment: this page use JavaScript to add items to page - you can't get it with `request` and `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` because they can't run JavaScript. You may need `Selenium` to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: BTW: next time turn off JavaScript in browser and reload page to see what Python can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @furas points out, for pages that rely on Javascript for content (which is most of them, these days), you'll need to use something like [selenium](https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/) to control an actual web browser. A simple solution might look something like this:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> d = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> d.get('https://www.google.com/get/sunroof/building/34.00192560211979/-81.21430071233021/#?f=buy')
>>> [e.text for e in d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.panel-fact-text')]
['1,581 hours of usable sunlight per year', '134,199 sq feet available for solar panels']
>>> d.close()
```